# Javascript variable visibility

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables, scope

I'm new in javascript world. Reading about the variables scope and I think I got the idea behind. I did some experiments and I'm having a situation here which gives me unexpected results. Here's what I mean

```
var x = 0;

function set(){
  x++;
}

set();
console.log(x) // 1
```

At this point of the script the value of x is 1 as expected

```
total = 0;
var id = setInterval(function(){
 total++; 
}, 10);
console.log(total); // 0
```

At this point of the script the value of total is always 0. I've checked and I'm sure the value of total is incremenated. So what's wrong with the second example and why the value of global variable total is not changed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using setInterval, which creates an interval **after** which the the function(passed as argument to the setInterval function) is executed periodically,

read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval

So, here-

```
total = 0;
var id = setInterval(function(){
 total++; 
}, 10);
console.log(total); // 0

 console.log(total); is executed before then the function inside the `setInterval` executes(aftyer a delay of 10ms).
```

You can try this

```
total = 0;

    var id = setInterval(function(){
     total++; 
     console.log(total);
    }, 10);
```

in this case the total is printed after it is been incremented

Answer (score 0):

Its because java script is asynchronous. console.log will be executed first and thereafter the function inside setInterval will be executed as it has been given 10 millisecond of delay...

To see the incremented value of 'total', you can run the below given code just after the setInterval.

```
 window.setTimeout(function(){
     console.log(total);
    }, 10);
```